# ION Drum Set Pedal Compatibility

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers, rock-band-3

I currently have a RB1 set that I got way back when it originally came out, but I've been considering getting a new set so that I can start playing pro drums on RB3. I figure that if I'm going to get a new set, I might as well splurge a little and get an ION set for myself.

My hangup is this: After my original RB1 drum pedal broke I bought two of [these pedals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001VIF550), which also came with a double-bass adapter. I really like the feel of the double-bass setup, and I really like the pedals themselves. I don't want to lose the ability to use these.

In looking at the specs for the ION set, it appears that they use 1/4" cables/connectors for the pads and the pedal. Is this correct? If so, would it be possible to use my current double-bass adapter and pedals with an ION set if I pick up an 1/8" to 1/4" adapter? I'm mostly concerned that the adapter won't work, though I also don't know if the pedals would even work on their own either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work with an adapter but the build quality on that pedal will feel disappointing once you have the all metal to compare it to. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure the ION pedal is nice - and I may really like it once I try it - but it's also good to know that I can continue using my current pedals if I want to.